# Ubuntu installation (space issue)

Tags: 14.04, disk-management

I am installing Ubuntu with my pre installed Windows 8.1.
I am confused about disk space.I want to install ubuntu in 50GB partition.How much memory should i assign to Swap, Home, and ubuntu installation.

I am not going to store pictures, movies or other files in my home directory.I am going to use Ubuntu for Programming purpose only, Specially for Ruby on Rails.I will install lot of programs in Ubuntu like Rubymine, Git, RoR etc.

My RAM is 2GB and I have dual core processor

Please suggest me memory size for each partition as i am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: I referd that but cant find solution

Comment: @EliahKagan can u tell me partitioning size as my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 50 GB ought to be enough for Ubuntu itself. I gave it a combined 25 GB (`/`, `/boot`, `/usr` and `/var`), which is far more than necessary even though I would consider myself a power user (with multiple IDEs, a DBMS, a web server and a VM environment).
- The size of your `/home` partition depends on your needs and is the same you would expect for the same kind of data on Windows (plus games if you want to use the default storage location of Steam, because that's on `/home` by default).

It is possible and relatively safe to change the size and layout of existing partitions with tools like (G)Parted, if your needs turn out to be different at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit take less than 5 GB. Just in case I will set about 2GB on swap partition (because you have minimal recommended memory for 64 bit system). In most cases application installs in e.g /user/lib not in home folder. This folder purpose is to hold your configuration data, cache files, documents, music, video etc. For programming purpose only I will consider not to have home partition at all and set something about 30 GB for all.